# Can printing cout << '\n' garble text output?

Tags: c++, newline, cout

I have a simple program to test a function I'm writing that detects if a text file for a maze is valid.  The only allowed characters are `'0'`, `'1'`, `' '` (space) and `'\n'` (newline).  However, when I execute the code with a sample text file, I get some strange results.  The third line of the following image should read "Found an illegal character [char] at [location] in maze [number]" before printing the imported maze as shown, which it does and it matches the file.

[image]

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fileName = "Mazes/Invalid4.txt";
    string tempMaze;
    int createdMazes = 0;
    cout << "\nAttempting to open " << fileName;
    fstream thing;
    thing.open(fileName.c_str());
    if(thing.is_open())
    {
        cout << "\nHurray!";
        stringstream mazeFromFile;
        mazeFromFile << thing.rdbuf();
        tempMaze = mazeFromFile.str();
        for(int i = 0; i < tempMaze.size(); i++)
        {
            // test to make sure all characters are allowed
            if(tempMaze[i] != '1' && tempMaze[i] != '0' && tempMaze[i] != ' ' && tempMaze[i] != '\n') 
            {
                cout << "\nFound an illegal character \"" << tempMaze[i] << "\" at " << i << " in maze " << ++createdMazes << ": \n" << tempMaze;
                return 1;
            }
        }
        cout << " And with no illegal characters!\n" << tempMaze << "\nFinished printing maze\n";
        return 0;
    }

    else cout << "\nAw...\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible that the text files aren't breaking lines with `'\n'`?  What's going on here?

Comment: Hi! Did you try to check the file contents in HEX-editor? Lines also can be broken by Windows break sequence "\r\n".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text file most likely has line endings as CRLF (`\r\n`). When you output CR, it will move the cursor to the beginning of the line. In essence, you're first writing 'Found an illegal character \"', then moving the cursor to the beginning of the line and writing the rest on top of it. You need to handle the line breaks differently to fix this.

Comment: Can I check for the `'\r'` character then?  I tried that but then it gave the output of the first character of every maze being invalid.  Can I read the file into a string a different way?

Comment: You can check for the `\r` like you're checking for `\n`, it's no different. Then just discard it later if you don't need it.

Comment: Okay I don't know why that wasn't working before.  Great explanation for the garbled text though.